# Delete EventRelation also delete Event when using DELETE request with sObject Collections

Tags: event, delete, composite

I am getting an issue that when i use DELETE request with sObject Collections, to delete an EventRelation, it also delete the main event.

`DELETE /vXX.X/composite/sobjects?ids=recordId,recordId`

An event can have a few attendees, so that if an attendee is removed, the main event should not be deleted.

Request: `eventRelationToDelete: [ '0RE2v00000Wkr5zGAB' ]`

Response Body: `"[{\"id\":\"00U2v00002NOJEOEA5\",\"success\":true,\"errors\":[]}]"`

You can see the Id in response is different from request, and this Id is an Event Id which is not correct. It should be EventRelation Id.

Answer (score 0):

When creating Events with Attendees, a child Event record is created and assigned to each Attendee. It  is likely that the event that gets deleted is not the main event but a child event because without an attendee, it has no meaning.

You can check the child event by querying the `IsChild` field on event.